# Is it possible to copy src/myapp.app.src to ebin/myapp.app in Emakefile?

Tags: erlang, build-process

I would like to keep my erlang app file in `src/<myapp>.app.src` and copy it to `ebin/<myapp>.app` when I build. Ideally, I'd like to use Emakefile to build, but I don't see an option for copying a file, only for compiling targets.

Is there a compile option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer exactly to your question, but if you build your application with [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar) you will get this feature (and much more)

Comment: That was the conclusion I came to as well. Even more than copying .app.src, `rebar create-app appid=<myapp>` will create the boilerplate app file as well as the *_app.erl and the first supervisor, copied to ebin/ with `rebar compile`.